# TTS reads out received sms, if sms exceeds normal 160 characters - will stop

Tags: android, sms, text-to-speech

as in title.  Have TTS reading out received messages.  But if the message exceeds 160 characters, it will no read the rest (which I assume is technically a second text, linked into one "big" message by the network provider) How can I modify my code so that if the sms is bigger than the standard single message, I can read it all out?
Here is a snippet of my code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
            int n; 
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
            for (n = 0; n<messages.length; n++){
                    smsMessage[n] =             SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])messages[n]); 
            }

            String sms1 = smsMessage[0].getMessageBody();       
            /**Send variable to the class handling TTS, to be read out-loud by the corresponding method */

            SpeakerActivity.speakSMS(sms1);
```

Comment: Sorry, formatting messed up. piece missing is: for (n = 0; n<messages.length; n++){
 smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
    }//end for loop

Comment: Have you inspected the return value of getMessageBody() to see what you're actually getting? It may be that a single long text message spans multiple entries in that array.

Comment: I not sure I understand, yock.  Do you mean that maybe smsMessage[1].getMessageBody(); may contain "more" of the message after 160 characters?

Comment: Right on the button.  Thanks, dunno why I didn't try that in the first place.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm going to post this as an answer so that passers-by might see. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each member of the array in your example contains a 160 character part of a message. If the message happens to exceed 160 characters, though Android stitches these together in the default SMS app, they will be represented in parts in your array. You'll need to iterate over that array to find the additional pieces of each long message.

Comment: Yock, see my issue below.  Can you think of a work around that could solve this?

Comment: Probably be best to start a new question with the relevant code sample. There's probably a simple solution to loop through the array, but it's hard to post answers in comments.

Answer (score 0):

smsMessage[1].getMessageBody(); 
smsMessage[2].getMessageBody(); 
etc contain the "rest" of the sms.  Solved.

Comment: Actually, problem with this.  It works, but lets say you have it set up to read out upto 3 sms messages.  If the message is less then that, you get a run time error.  Need to implement error checking or set up something that will ensure if one message received read it, if two messages received, read it (and the first) etc...  I played around with this, and while it doesn't crash anymore, it will stop reading after 160 characters again.